VRF deployment subscriptionID out of bounds
Trying to deploy VRF2.5 in Sepolia testnet. I'm using the subscription method with the subscription manager capability at https://vrf.chain.link/
I'm then able to fund the contract using the interface and get success there.
When I load the VRFv2Consumer.sol in remix and attempt to deploy it, I am getting an error that the  subscriptionID is out of bounds even though I just finished copying it from the deployed and funded subscription contract. In watching the great youtube by Richard, the interface looks different from 9-months ago (of course) but he shows copying a 4-digit subscription ID number. Maybe the numbering  has changed since then but now the numbers showing up on the subscription manager page looks more the length of a contract ID?
Error below. Any help is appreciated.
creation of VRFv2Consumer errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: value out-of-bounds (argument=null, value="58613058720565841130526624844714146922486454348281868887895625676722180052659", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)
If I place a 4-digit ID in there it will deploy but, of course it doesn't connect to the subscription contract.
One other detail that MAY be important. I am getting periodic signing errors in metamask when "creating" a subscription contract on the manager interface. I'm guessing the subscription manager is having some issues?

I've run through manual deployment, sidestepping the manager interface and the same result occurs when doing it using the manual process.

The variable uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId in the Raffle contract can't keep large numbers.
Change it to uint256 private immutable i_subscriptionId.
Then, upon requesting random words, you need to cast it to uint64 as the method accepts uint64:
function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /* performData */) external override {
    ...
    uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
        i_gasLane,
        uint64(i_subscriptionId), <-- cast it
        REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
        uint32(i_callbackGasLimit),
        NUM_WORDS
    );
        emit RequestedRaffleWinner(requestId);
    }


Yerges}(https://stackoverflow.com/users/25192888/al-maslowski-yerges)
You are using a VRFv2Consumer.sol with a VRF 2.5 subscription
Check it out a VRF 2.5 consumer
Getting Started with Chainlink VRF V2.5
Click on Open in Remix

By any chance did you prefix the subscriptionId with '0x', because I was also having the same issue, but it got resolved when I removed the '0x' prefix and only used the id.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
